# How to toggle Device Mode on a popup window in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a web app with a chat that opens in a new popup window. Normally, in Chrome I can hit F12 and click the icon of a smart phone to toggle it. But in the popup window this icon does not appear. This is important for me since I need to throttle the connection of the popup in order to simulate a user disconnecting from the chat.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be currently possible. I've opened a [ticket for you](http://crbug.com/500225). Meanwhile you have couple of options:

- open popup in a regular window (copy paste the url, or modify `window.open` call to open a new tab instead of a separate window),
- create a Chrome extension that uses [debugger API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger) to send `emulateNetworkConditions` message to your popup window
- or try hacking DevTools like so:

  - open DevTools (**A**) for your popup
  - focus on DevTools window and open another DevTools (**B**) for that window using a keyboard shortcut (F12/alt+cmd+J)
  - in the console of the DevTools **B** call `WebInspector.overridesSupport.setEmulationEnabled(true)` (to enable emulation) and then `WebInspector.overridesSupport.settings.networkConditions.set({throughput: 1.5 * 1024, latency: 40});` (to enable network throttling)

Comment: From the ticket: `Tested on all OS using chrome M20 - 20.0.1086.0  and observed there is no device mode enabled in chrome for pop-up windows, Considering this as feature request and marking it as untriaged.` and `This was just changed recently (see  issue 496081 ). Full Device Mode has no sense for popup window, but network throttling does. Let's make it clear here.`

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps easier way as of today is to install chrome extension which will allow you to open preview in new tab instead of popup. There you can have the same icon to toggle to mobile. Below is the extension:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-companion/jmekfmbnaedfebfnmakmokmlfpblbfdm?hl=en