# Enable/control Chrome device mode from an extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to enter device mode and change it's options from a regular chrome extension (presumably triggering the debugger first)?  (this seems to have been asked back in 2014 by several people with no answers, wondering if anything has changed)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to toggle Device Mode on a popup window in Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786150/how-to-toggle-device-mode-on-a-popup-window-in-chrome)