# Open page in new browser window with device mode dev tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Using `window.open` to open a new window in chrome the device icon in the dev tools is not present.

```
window.open('https://google.com/', '_blank');
```

I feel like this is a bug in Chrome as I'm not sure why they would want to prevent it? Or am I missing a way?

I saw another question but the bug that was logged was about network throttling not allowing device tool available. [How to toggle Device Mode on a popup window in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786150/how-to-toggle-device-mode-on-a-popup-window-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a bug and have opened an [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=642329)